# no match for operator+= error with atomic<__uint128_t>

Tags: addition, atomic

I want add value to a atomic<__uint128_t> but i have this error

```
erreur : no match for ‘operator+=’ (operand types are ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::atomic<__int128 unsigned> > >::value_type {aka std::atomic<__int128 unsigned>}’ and ‘const value_type {aka const std::atomic<__int128 unsigned>}’)
niveau[ranka(pre)]+=etage_fils[i];
```

with

```
"typedef __uint128_t longuint;"
```

my code :

```
vector<atomic<longuint>> (vector<atomic<longuint>> const & etage_fils, int eta){

vector<atomic<longuint>> niveau(mahonian(n,eta-2));
int limite = mahonian(n, eta-1);

cilk_for (int i = 0; i < limite; ++i)
{
    vector<Permut> parents = prec(unrank(eta-1, i));
    for (Permut const & pre : parents)
    {
        niveau[ranka(pre)]+=etage_fils[i];
    }
}
return niveau;
```

}

I tried

```
niveau[ranka(pre)].fetch_add(etage_fils[i];
```

but don't works

Any help will be appreciated. thanks :)